# Value of type ... has no member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello I'm new to Swift and I'm learning it on iTunes U, the Stanford University course. And I'm programming a calculator. The instructor in the course video has the same code, software and same version of XCode.

Here's the relevant code for ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var display: UILabel!

    private var displayValue: Double {

        get {
            return Double(display.text!)!

        }

        set {
            display.text = String(newValue)

        }
    }

    ...

    private var brain = calculatorBrain()

    @IBAction private func performOperation(sender: UIButton) {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            brain.setOperand(displayValue)
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
        }

        if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
        }
        displayValue = brain.result
    }
}
```

The error is in the last sentence: `displayValue = brain.result`
This is the error: Value of type 'CalculatorBrain' has no value 'result'

This is the CalculatorBrain code:

```
import Foundation

    func multiply(op1: Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
         return op1 * op2 
    } 

    class calculatorBrain {
    private var accumulator = 0.0

    func setOperand(operand: Double) {
        accumulator = operand

    }

    var operations: Dictionary<String,Operation> = [
        "π" : Operation.Constant(M_PI),
        "e" : Operation.Constant(M_E),
        "√" : Operation.UnaryOperation(sqrt),
        "cos" : Operation.UnaryOperation(cos),
        "×" : Operation.BinaryOperation(multiply),
        "=" : Operation.Equals


    ]
    enum Operation {
        case Constant(Double)
        case UnaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
        case BinaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double)
        case Equals
    }

    func performOperation(symbol: String) {
        if let operation = operations[symbol] {
            switch operation {
            case .Constant(let value): accumulator = value
            case .UnaryOperation(let function): accumulator = function(accumulator)
            case .BinaryOperation(let function):
            case .Equals: break
            }

        }
    } 
}

struct PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
    var BinaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
    var firstOperand: Double 
}

var result: Double { 
    get {
        return 0.0 
    }
}
```

So what's the problem?

Comment: It would help if you fix the indenting so that one can see where a definition starts and ends.

Comment: Your `{}`s and indenting is all messed up but it looks like your `result` var is outside of the class definition

Comment: I think once you move result inside the class, you'll also have a problem with mismatched types.  "displayValue" is a UILabel and "result" is a Double.  I suspect you may want: displayValue.text = "slash(brain.result)"....that "slash" is the symbol, not the word, but the comments don't seem to let me put that symbol there.

Comment: @conarch Missing the backslash: `displayValue.text = "\(brain.result)"`, or `displayValue.text = String(brain.result)`

Comment: Please reduce the code you've posted to [the minimum necessary to display the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I went ahead and fixed up the question

Comment: @conarch, that isn't true. `displayValue` is a double, `display` is a `UILabel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of result

```
var result: Double { 
    get {
        return 0.0 
    }
}
```

here, to inside of the class:

```
class calculatorBrain {

    var result: Double { 
        get {
            return 0.0 
        }
    }


...


}
```

Since you are defining result outside of the `CalculatorBrain` class so you get the error:

> Value of type 'CalculatorBrain' has no value 'result'